# Javascript: Create Function that executes a callback function at random intervals on average of 1~2 times per minute

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, setinterval

I have this problem that came up and I realized that I don't understand callbacks nearly as good as I should.
The way it's worded makes me think that I need to make it a set interval, but then you see that there is the syntax of "function randomExecution(callback) {}" and that really trips me up.

On top of all of this, this problem really makes me realize how inefficient I am at breaking down a problem into smaller parts. I see the "make sure it's on average about 1~2 times per minute" and I just get lost.

(I get that i can be less than 10 seconds that I have the min set to, but I'm pretty lost here and that was my only solution to make it so it doesn't get called within ten seconds)

What am I doing wrong here?
Also, any advice on how to approach questions like this would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

The Problem:

```
function randomExecution(callback) {
 // start an interval that executes `callback()` at random intervals
 // make sure it's on average about 1~2 times per minute
 // make sure it doesn't execute twice within 10 seconds
}
```

My attempt:

```
function randomExecution(callback) {
  const min = 10
  const max = 120
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
  // callback = console.log('Wait for ' + random + ' seconds')
  return random
} 

setInterval(console.log(`hi, after ${randomExecution()} seconds`) , randomExecution)
```

Comment: There is a problem with your ```setInterval``` syntax, you should use ```setInterval(callback, ms);``` with ms being the amount of milliseconds you would like to set the interval at. ```setInterval(() => { functionality }, ms);``` or ```setInterval(function(){ functionality }, ms);```

Comment: As the commenter below stated, I should be using setTimeout() instead of setInterval(); since I want to call it multiple times. This was a total brain fart on my end thinking that setInterval and setTimeout were swapped in what they do. 

Thanks for the comment!

Comment: setInterval also calls the function repeatedly, it only starts calling after the interval, with setTimeout it calls the function immediately

Comment: @b4andy here I thought that setTimeout only calls the function once after the random timeout. Where the setInterval has it running continuously with the length of timeout between them. Either way, I suppose I'm not entirely sure how to recheck the interval set. LIke if it started with 3s (random number), wouldn't it just keep running the function every 3 seconds? Not sure how to keep reapplying the random interval so it meets the question parameters of calling 1~2 times per minute.

Cheers! I appreciate all the help so far!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that you use the function [SetInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), which, as the name suggests, is used to call a specified function repeatedly after a fixed interval. A better approach would be to create a recursive loop with [SetTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), where your code would look like this:

```js
function example() {
    console.log('See you soon!')
}

function randomExecution(callback) {
    // start an interval that executes `callback()` at random intervals
    // make sure it's on average about 1~2 times per minute
    // make sure it doesn't execute twice within 10 seconds

    const min = 30
    const max = 60
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

    setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
        randomExecution(callback);
    }, random * 1000);
}

randomExecution(example)
```

Comment: Thank you! I initially had setTimeout, but I had them totally mixed around in my head as to what they actually do. 
Why is is the callback function in your example just "callback()"? Is it that it is just a placeholder for the function you will be passing as an arguement(ie; "example()")?
I assumed the `callback()` the question is calling for was simply a placeholder for whatver function I chose to callback in the end. Perhaps I am not able to comprehend the original question fully. 

Anyways, cheers for the reply!

Comment: @LovelyAndy The `callback` refers to the argument of the function itself, so when I call randomExecution(example), it takes that argument (which is the defined function example) and runs it, by putting `()` after it. Don't pity yourself, it's something that takes practice to get used to, and we're all making mistakes and keep learning.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explaination and words.
I thought that setTimeout only calls the function once after the random timeout is. Where the setInterval has it running continuously with the length of timeout between them. Just not positive how to continuously call it with a new interval set each time. WIth your help though I've got more clues to get this problem figured out. thanks!